# how to hide dynamically created canvas objects after reaching the end of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I've created HTML5 canvas objects dynamically, by cloning them at a set interval of time. Now, I need to make each of them disappear after they reach the end of the screen. This is the code I've used to create the canvas objects.
HTML code

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>

<br><br>
<script src="myjs1.js"></script>         
<canvas id="test" class="test"></canvas>          
</body>
</html>
```

MYJS1.JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var c = document.getElementById("test");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var h=ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 50%, 50%)';    
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
    ctx.font="30px Arial";

    ctx.fillText(0,250,75);
            ctx.stroke();



setInterval(function() {
     var el = $("#test"),  
     newone = el.clone(true);
     el.before(newone);


},5000);

var i=0;

setInterval(function() {
    i++;
var e = document.getElementById("test");
var ctx2 = e.getContext("2d");
ctx2.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 50%, 50%)';    
ctx2.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);

        ctx2.font="30px Arial";
    ctx2.fillText(i,250,75 );
    ctx2.stroke();
},5000);
});
```

If I use the following code, it's stopping the blocks from being created after the given condition, not making the first created block disappear.

```
if(i>10){
$('#test:first').remove();
}
```

`'#test:last'` also gives the same result.
Can someone please help me out.

Comment: first of: IDs have to be unique per document, use the class selector and maybe the index of the element to reference

Comment: how to create the canvas elements without using the clone? How do I assign a unique id to each of them? And, I'm not supposed to use any button clicks.